# How to print the paragraph field translation value in twig template

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I am trying to access the nested paragraph field inside my twig template.

```
{% for items in item['#paragraph'].get_aw_title_details%}
  {{ item.entity.field_award.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

When I am using this syntax it is always returning the English content. Translation content is not visible for me. For chinese also it is giving the english content

Answer (score 3):

Normally it's a better idea to process (or even better let Drupal process) the field values in PHP.

If there is no other way you can use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) and its newly added entity translation filter:

```
{% set entity = item.entity|translation %}
{{ entity.field_award.value }}
```

See https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#entity-translation